# Messaging Webhook for Microsoft skype bot

Tags: azure, chat, skype, microsoft-skype-bot

I'm setting up a Microsoft Skype bot, and I want to be able to have it post messages to individual and group chats. I have added a bot at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/manage and checked the Messaging checkboxes, but there's a field for "Messaging Webhook", which says "The HTTPS URL to send chat messages and content to. Required if you have a chat capability". What do I put in this field? There's no obvious help link. Do I need to set up an Azure website?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Node.js:

If you want to test your bot locally, you need to follow the instructions for ngrok described in the comments of [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/demo-skype-calling/app.js) and [this guide](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/calling/UniversalBot/#navtitle). Once you run ngrok, you will obtain a HTTPS URL such as `https://62a8271e.ngrok.io`. You then need to append `/api/calls` to this URL, i.e. the webhook URL you need to enter in the Skype channel configurations and as environment variable "CALLBACK_URL" would be `https://62a8271e.ngrok.io/api/calls`.

If you want to test your bot globally and you have deployed it as an Azure web app, you need to replace the ngrok URL with your bot URL, i.e. the URL should look something like `https://yourbot.azurewebsites.net/api/calls`. Don't forget to add this URL as an environment variable in your web app settings as well.