# How can I setting webhook callback url for Bot Framework (Skype)?

Tags: botframework

I need to setting URL for a service that was been receive event for new messages. According to Microsoft documentation I can set the url for, e.g., Facebook (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#generate-a-page-access-token), but I can't find information about setting url for Skype.

But I can specify a message endpoint for my bot. The message endpoint is a webhook url?

Sorry for my bad English

See also: [Messaging Webhook for Microsoft skype bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632817/messaging-webhook-for-microsoft-skype-bot)

PS: about web hooks for Skype: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/webhooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using C# or node but I will try my best to answer both.

The Webhook is just the endpoint for your calling controller in C# so for example in the [sample from the botbuilder repository in C#](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleIVRBot) They are using the `CallController.cs` Your webhook would be `https://{your site}/api/call`.

In [the sample from node](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/tree/master/Node/examples/demo-skype-calling) they are using `server.post('/api/calls', connector.listen());`  so your webhook url would be `https://{your site}/api/calls` in this setup